# Rails: Using Render on Page Causing Missing Template Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, render

I am trying to render html from `app/views/companies/new.html.erb` on one of my pages, but I get the error:

> Missing partial companies/_new.html.erb with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw,
>   :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:   *
>   "D:/Documents/Code/pandora/app/views"   *
>   "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-extras-0.0.6/app/views"
>   * "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-d44c1b8a57cc/app/views"
>   * "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"
>   * "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/devise-b12658782ff4/app/views"

This is what I have to render in my html.erb file that I am trying to load when I get this error: `<%= render "companies/new.html.erb" %>`

What could be causing this and how could I fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: In a view render will only look for partials, so it's looking for a file called `_new.html.erb`.  What exactly are you trying to do?  If this is on the create action in the controller you can do `render :new` which will tell the controller to render the files for the new action.

Comment: What I am trying to do I load/render the html from new.html.erb into another html file, so that I do not have to copy paste the whole thing and so that when I make changes to the file I do not need to go into every file that uses it and change it there also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `<%= render "companies/new.html.erb" %>`, it will look for `_new.html.erb`(a partial file). Try using the below code to render `new.html.erb`

```
<%= render template: "companies/new.html.erb" %>
```

Also, check [***render***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render) for more info.